Modifying list while iterating in python
I currently have a situation which looks something like this:
 for element in some_list:
     if(some_condition==True):
         some_list.clear()
         some_list.append(new_elements)

However, this is giving me some weird behaviour. The for-loop only runs for as many iterations as the original length of some_list.
How can I fix this so I can make modifications to the list, and still have the loop behave correctly?
Here is my actual code in case you want to see it. It is part of an algorithm for checking isomorphisms between graphs.
  if (len(v_in_g1_with_color) + len(v_in_g2_with_color)) >= 4:
      for vertex2 in v_in_g2_with_color:
          if(sorted(refinement2[0][0].values()) == sorted(refinement2[1][0].values())):
              v += 1
              vertex_to_be_checked = list((colours1.keys()))[v]
              v_in_g2_with_color.clear()
              for key, value in colours2.items():
                  if value == colours1[vertex_to_be_checked]:
                      v_in_g2_with_color.append(key)
              continue

I couldn't come up with a solution yet. But the expected behaviour is to be able to modify the list and iterate over the new modified version of the list, instead of the old one.

Iterate over the complete list again from beginning? Then you need an additional while-loop containing the for-loop. When the list is changed, break the for-loop and start it again. Additionally you may need a boolean variable to tell the while-loop when to exit.

This seems like a reasonable solution. I will try to implement this!

Modifying a list while iterating over it using a for loop can lead to unexpected behavior. When you call some_list.clear(), the loop's internal index advances to the next element that should have existed after the cleared elements. However, since the list is now empty, the loop terminates.
If I understand the problem, you can use list comprehension:
v_in_g2_with_color = [key for key, value in colours2.items() if value == colours1[vertex_to_be_checked]]

This creates a new list containing elements from colours2 that meet the condition, effectively filtering and modifying the list without affecting the original loop.

SO basically the problem is occuring in the length of the list as when the iteration is occuring the length of list becomes smaller ,
Here, i would recommend to use fixed length of for loop as :
for i in range (0,len(some_list) :
if(some_condition == True ):
    some_list.clear()
    some_list.append(new_elements)

Correct me if i got the question wrong ?
